# Regex Replace Not Replacing String on Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following line of code to update the contents of certain cells:

```
cmb['Skill'] = cmb['Skill'].replace(({'Application Programming Interface (API)': 'APIs'}), regex=True)
```

I have no idea why this won't work.... I've tried the following as well with no luck:

```
cmb['Skill'] = cmb['Skill'].astype(str) #adding this beforehand

cmb = cmb.replace(({'Application Programming Interface (API)': 'APIs'}), regex=True)
cmb['Skill'] = cmb['Skill'].replace(({'Application Programming Interface (API)': 'APIs'}), inplace=True)
cmb['Skill'] = cmb['Skill'].str.replace(({'Application Programming Interface (API)': 'APIs'}), regex=True)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it seems that you don't need regex here, so try `regex=False`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> cmb['Skill'] = cmb['Skill'].replace(({'Application Programming Interface (API)': 'APIs'}), regex=True)
> ```

Notice that `(` `)` parens are special w.r.t. regexes.

If you try this simpler regex it should work:

```
... .replace(({r'Application Programming Interface': ...
```

Here is something which *almost* means the same
as your original:

```
... .replace(({r'Application Programming Interface .API.': ...
```

Or you can drive yourself crazy with escaping
special characters. Notice that raw `r`-strings
help with that.

```
... .replace(({r'Application Programming Interface \(API\)': ...
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape if you'd rather not drive yourself crazy :)

Comment: zomg, tilde is special?!? `~~` means (or will mean) symmetric difference: A⊖B = (A∪B)\(A∩B) . Right, _now_ I've been driven crazy.